# Can adding rows to a matrix decrease its column rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, matlab, matrix-rank

Suppose that $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with $m > n$. Now consider a matrix $B$ which is formed by adding new rows to the matrix $A$. Is it possible for the column rank of $B$ to be smaller than that of $A$?

I cannot see why this is possible. I would expect that by increasing the number of rows, the column rank should either increase or stay the same. That is, you're either adding linearly independent or dependent rows with the latter not changing the rank.

I am asking because I've tried this numerically in Matlab and I saw that the rank can decrease if rows are added. I am not sure if this is just a numerical issue especially considering that I'm taking the rank of a 400000 by 10 matrix...

Comment: It is absolutely a numerical issue. Just think about it conceptually. The rows that were linearly independent stay linearly independent. The ones that you add may be either dependent upon them or independent, but you can't lose the ones you already had.

Comment: I agree but I cannot believe how much the rank would fluctuate from a numerical point of view. If I start with a 100 by 10 matrix, the rank is 10 but when I go up to 400000 rows, the rank decreases to 2!

Comment: I'm not a numerical analyst, so I cannot explain what's going on, but you're doing something very ill-conditioned.

Comment: What are you using for the rank determination, are there parameters to tune it? If it is the estimation of some kind of effective rank based on singular values or similar, then indeed you can introduce with the additional rows a size difference by a factor of $10^{-3}$, or so, after the second singular value, which could be used to detect that the effective rank is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Note that adding rows can only increase the row rank. Now use the theorem that row rank equals column rank.

I don’t have a good explanation for why Matlab is acting strangely, but I *strongly* recommend that you check some small examples before slamming your CPU with the scary large computations.